# How can I run C code in specific hardware setting

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, c, arm, matlab

i write face detection on matlab and converted to c to use on mcu (STM32F4)

now i want to know the code can run on this type of mcu

there is tool or something to test this?

Comment: Try ARM-Keil ...

Comment: You have already asked a similar but a bit more elaborative question on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68534755/how-can-i-run-c-code-in-specific-hardware-setting). Please do not cross-post questions. It is not clear what and how you converted. It is almost definite that a code that was converted to run on x86 won't run on STM32

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean by the question- C code will generally run on any platform for which there’s a C compiler.  Are you interested in whether the code will run at all (perhaps limited by RAM) or whether performance will be adequate?

Comment: You need a c-compiler that supports the stm32F4, and an stm32f4.  The compilers are usually free, and there are development boards with those microcontrollers available in the $15-$25 range (USD)

Comment: @Frog i want to know that the RAM is enough to run the compiled code or not

Comment: When you compile with the right compiler, it should tell you how much RAM you need.  You can look up how much RAM the microcontroller has, or buy one with enough RAM

Comment: This is not how it works with embedded programs. You *know* what your memory size is and *you* are laying down the memory map to contain different sections of the program in it in a form of a linker script. When you compile and link it using this script it might tell you that certain sections do not fit into their dedicated boundaries. Of course, sometimes vendors provide a full development environment that is hiding these details.

Comment: @ScottSeidman which compiler shows needed RAM?

Comment: I'm pretty sure every compiler for an embedded microcontroller that I've ever used -- though it may just throw an error if you exceed the ram of the target microprocessor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should compile the code for STM32F4 (using [STM32cubeide](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stm32cubeide.html) or [Keil](https://www.keil.com/) or [IAR Embedded Workbench](https://www.iar.com/products/architectures/arm/iar-embedded-workbench-for-arm/)) and after that you can use [Proteus](https://www.labcenter.com/) for simulation.

I personally didn't try Proteus simulation for STM32F4, but they are available in Pick Device section of Proteus.

[image: Pick Device]

Answer (score 4):

You need a c-compiler that supports the stm32F4, and an stm32f4. The compilers are usually free, and there are development boards with those microcontrollers available in the $15-$25 range (USD)

If you are starting from the position of never having used any of these tools before, you probably have about 20-40 hours of hard work to do to set up and learn how to use the environment.

You're probably better off using a single board computer, like the Raspberry Pi or a better competitor, as your code will be more likely to work (for many reasons).

A better answer would need to come from somebody who is familiar with the Matlab tools you used to convert your code to c.  The tools I'm aware of for that purpose aren't targeted for microcontrollers, but I'm behind the times on this.